# from asp to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Is it posible to convert an ASP app to ASP.NET? I prefer to work with Visual Studio, in ASP.NET rather than just ASP.  I need to do this because I'm stuck trying to watch an ASP page, as I don´t know how to work with ASP, I'm trying to see the code of ASP (classic ASP) in Visual Studio, maybe I need to make some changes, but I don´t know what the changes are.  I did several changes in my app, like put a button to select and unselect checkboxes, but I can´t see any change or image, this way to works is different that the way I'm use to it, well,it's supossed this code works, (the problem is I can´t see any change):

```
<td align="center" colspan="3">
  <input type="button" name="btn_seleccionar_todo" value="Seleccionar todo" onclick="javascript:marcar(this.form);">
</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3">
  <input type="button" name="btn_desseleccionar_todo" value="Seleccionar todo" onclick="javascript:desmarcar(this.form);">
</td>

function marcar()
{
  for (i=0;i<form.usuarios.options.length;i++)
  {
    form.usuarios.options[i].checked=true;
  } 
}

function desmarcar()
{
  for(i=0;i<form.usuarios.options.length;i++)
  {
      form.usuarios.options[i].checked=false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get your example. I see some html and some javascript code. I see no ASP nor ASP.NET code. What have you tried?

Comment: The code you posted is JavaScript; I see nothing in your posted code or markup to suggest this is classic ASP.  JavaScript works the same in .NET as it does in ASP.

Comment: You're probably posting the output of the ASP. The code is processed and removed server side before the client sees the HTML. Please post some source code.

Comment: yes, is javascript, I need to add that code to my asp app, but first I need to transform asp classic to asp.net, the code below is just an example, because I don´t know how to see what I'm changing in my app, that kind of changes are that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching fundamental technologies is a huge undertaking and not to be taken lightly. You definitely shouldn't approach it as a simple translation of VBScript into C#... you need to rewrite the entire thing using the newly selected technology idiomatically.  Its like using Google translate to communicate via email or chat with someone who speaks a different language - it could work, but not really very well.